# on startup login screen has default wallpaper

Tags: kubuntu, startup, login-screen, desktop-background, sddm

I am on kubuntu 22.04 and when I start up my device, login screen shows the default login background not the one I set in settings.

waking from sleep or locking screen shows correct login screen background

problem is only with first login screen that shows on startup

ps. I do not mean different sddm I mean the background wallpaper shown in the login screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the lockscreen customization is user-based and until one logs in, it will not take effect. simply edit the image used by sddm and it will show up on first startup.